# Serialization Purpose in a Complied Build

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I was reading Odin's docs and from there I noticed mentions that the serialization system is needed in the compiled build. AFAIK, Serialization is used for scene saving and inspector stuff - none of this is needed in the game-ready compiled build.

Then what's the purpose of serialization system in a compiled build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general [serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) means nothing more than storing certain values serialized into a file e.g. the Unity scene or any Assets like Prefabs or `ScriptableObject`s. You can basically open all of them in a texteditor and see their serialized version.

In general everything `serialized` means you can configure it in the Inspector and on runtime/in a build the instances will be generated using the serialized (stored) values for their fields instead of default ones.

Basically e.g. any serialized field like

```
[SerializeField] private float value;
```

or

```
public string someString;
```

works like this and ofcourse requires at least some kind of **de**serialization system on runtime and in a compiled build.

---

It is further possible to also use serialization and deserialization on runtime /in a build for e.g. converting classes from and to [`JSON`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual//JSONSerialization.html) or [`XMl`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer) or other formats or load and create assets or [AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html).

Therefore it makes completely sense to have (de)serialization systems in a build and it is very unlikely to find a system that has the serialization isolated from the deserialization.

---

Specific for the [Odin Inspector](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/odin-inspector-and-serializer-89041): It uses the [serialzation system](https://odininspector.com/tutorials/serialize-anything/odin-serializer-quick-start) to - how they say - *serialize everything*. This even allows you to store scene references in prefabs so the prefab once instantiated can restore the according references from the scene.